# What is the need for form::hidden in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http

I just wanted to ask for why form::hidden() is used in Laravel framework, that is, it is clear that within hidden method you can put PUT or Delete HTTP request methods but why can't we just use PUT or DELETE as method in a form. Yes, it is not possible and I have read loads of articles on that but for the beginner in web development it was unclear. Thus, can anyone explain in simple terms,

> firstly

, why to use POST as http method in a form and then below use Form::hidden('_method','PUT'). Do we just override POST with PUT.

> Secondly

, it is very important if anyone tries to explain in simple terms why PUT and DELETE are not supported in HTML without giving links to read. Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This methods were dropped on HTML5. The reason i'd love to know it too... https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-diff-20101019/#changes-2010-06-24

> 5.1. Changes since 24 June 2010
>
> Numerous changes to the HTML parsing algorithm based on implementation feedback.
>
> The hidden attribute now works for table-related elements.
>
> The canvas getContext() method is now defined to be able to handle multiple contexts better.
>
> The media elements' startTime IDL attribute was renamed to initialTime and startOffsetTime was added.
>
> The prefetch link relationship can now be used on a elements.
>
> The datetime attribute of ins and del no longer requires a time to be specified.
>
> **Using PUT and DELETE as HTTP methods for the form element is no longer supported**.
>
> The s element is no longer deprecated.
>
> The video element has a new audio attribute.

However, they were dropped just from HTML5, your server should still recognize request from HTML4 and prior versions. I haven't tried it myself, but, logic says they should work on older HTML versions. And that these fields should not be needed on older versions. Thats what logic says at least.

**Edit**

After some investigation, seems like my previous statement about it, being dropped just from HTML5 is true, but is true, because HTML5 is the only HTML standard that ever considered this methods. So what i said about this maybe working on previous versions, is false.

Comment: hi Erubiel, thank you for your solution, but I have two more questions and I really hope that you will answer. So, firstly why we declare post as a method of form <form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"></form And then declare PUT method. It means that POST method must be declared just as a convention and what if I omit it. The second question can you briefly explain with your own words why PUT and Delete was dropped in HTML 5. I hope for your help :)

Comment: 1. - because the more similar behavior to this methods (PUT, DELETE) occurs on POST. 2.- Originally, they were valid on html5, then they got removed! I guess that, as with every html, css, and script standard, they couldn't get all the major browser manufacturers to get inline with the specs at the same time, so they dropped it. Although i would expect that in the future they will come back.

Comment: please can you clarify 1. - because the more similar behavior to this methods (PUT, DELETE) occurs on POST. :) since, you know, I am new to web development. Thank you in advance

Comment: the more obvious difference between POST and GET is how the data appears to the user. on GET you will see the data on the URL, which is highly forgeable/modifiable/prone to expose data... on POST, the user will not see the variables that are being sent, unless its capturing using something like, web inspector. There are more differences, but that is the main difference. By standards, POST is made for sending/posting data... And GET is made for retrieving data. Though you can use GET for sending and POST for retrieving, that is bad practice.

Comment: So, basically you mean since PUT and DELETE have kind of similar meaning with Post we use first POST at the beginning of form tag.Right? sorry dude I just want to get the point once and for all :)

Comment: Yes, since, if they existed, would behave on the same way, you use POST... you can even just declare in your routes file the delete/put methods as post and they would work... but since is not standard for the framework, i would advice against it, just telling you, so you get more understanding of how they work.

Comment: Forgot to mention, you can use DELETE and PUT methods with javascript libraries like axios... though i dunno the workarounds this libraries make behind the scenes to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Form::hidden('_method','PUT')` is written after we have `POST` method in the form. It tells the Laravel which method to execute for the method. laravel has few methods; any, post, get, put, delete, patch.

You can simply use POST method and submit the form. But if you are going to use the resource type controller, then you should use the respective methods.

2. HTML only support get and post method. In default, html form method has get method.

Comment: Hi:), please can you clarify  "It tells the Laravel which method to execute for the method" which method? if you mean as HTTP method the why we would use POST and then define hidden method with PUT or DELETE. Please try to answer this question it is very important:)

Comment: I meant to say "It tells the Laravel which method to execute for the method added in the hidden field." if nothing is defined, then it will use get method

Comment: ok Suzan, look if we declare, say, PUT inside hidden, then will it mean PUT is a main http response if yes then why to declare POST at the beginning of form tag. Does it mean that POST+PUT=PUT it is just my assumption and if it true can we just use POST for both PUT and DELETE in a universal manner? Thank you for your attention:)

Comment: post  is used to hide the details from the URL just as in normal HTML form and `PUT` and `DELETE` are additional methods that are specifically used by Laravel Resources to  call save or delete  methods

Comment: is it possible to just use POST at the beginning of form tag without defining hidden method and accomplish update and delete functionality

Comment: yeah we can, that's what we do normally. `Route::post('/path','Controller@method');`

Answer (score 1):

"HTML" forms only have 2 methods: get and post (including HTML5).

That said, this is the way laravel came up with *to support calling the missing methods* `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` from a form directly.

### 1

> ### Laravel Form Method Spoofing
>
> HTML forms do not support `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` actions. So, when defining `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` **routes that are called from an HTML form** , you will need to add a hidden `_method` field to the form. The value sent with the `_method` field will be used as the HTTP request method
>   ([Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing))

### 2

HTML tag `form` was defined in that way. The form-data can be sent as URL variables (with method="get") or as HTTP post transaction (with method="post").

Comment: hi Edgardo, thank you for your solution, but I have two more questions and I really hope that you will answer. So, firstly why we declare post as a method of form <form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"></form And then declare PUT method. It means that POST method must be declared just as a convention anwhat if I omit it. The second question can you briefly explain with your own words why PUT and Delete was dropped in HTML 5. I hope for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides various routes for operations such as create, view, update and delete. The easier way to get all the routes for creating, editing, viewing and deleting would be to use [Laravel resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers).

I think your doubt will be clear if you visit the [Laravel resource controllers documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers). The route actions are simplified by using the terms such as `GET, POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE`. And you are right about the fact that HTML does not support `PUT/PATCH/DELETE` operations. But these are not the operations used in HTTP. Rather, this is for simplification of routes. This process is called form spoofing. For example, if you want to update something then you can use `Form::hidden('method', 'PUT')` method to perform form spoofing (i.e. letting the framework to know that you want to update something). Similarly, if you want to delete something, you can use `Form::hidden('method', "DELETE")`